# How to get three fields (one record) each counts different condition on the same field?

Tags: sql

I have:

```
CREATE TABLE Vote
    (`pid` int, `choice` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Vote
    (`pid`, `choice`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b'),
    (3, 'ana'),
    (4, 'aya'),
    (5, 'ayna'),
    (6, 'anya'),
    (7, 'x'),
    (8, 'y'),
    (9, 'z')
```

And I'm trying to find how many choices included 'n' but not 'y', how many included 'y' but not 'n' and how many either included both or included none.
This is what I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(v1.choice) AS n_not_y,COUNT(v2.choice) AS y_not_n,COUNT(v3.choice) AS rest
FROM Vote v1,Vote v2,Vote v3
WHERE v1.choice LIKE '%n%' AND v1.choice NOT LIKE '%y%' AND
      v2.choice LIKE '%y%' AND v2.choice NOT LIKE '%n%' AND
     ( (v3.choice NOT LIKE '%y%' AND v3.choice NOT LIKE '%n%') OR
     (v3.choice LIKE '%y%n%' OR v3.choice LIKE '%n%y%') )
```

But as you can see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b9c/7/0) it gives one row showing 12,12,12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your result shows 12,12,12 is that the `count` gets the number of returned rows regardless of their values.

You would use CASE for that as below

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN v1.choice LIKE '%n%' AND v1.choice NOT LIKE '%y%' THEN 1 ELSE O) AS n_not_y
SUM(CASE WHEN v2.choice LIKE '%y%' AND v2.choice NOT LIKE '%n%' THEN 1 ELSE O) AS y_not_n
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Since those are (logically) three separate queries, it makes most sense to basically, run them separately, and combine the results:

```
SELECT 
  (select count(*) from Vote 
   where choice LIKE '%n%' AND choice NOT LIKE '%y%') as n_not_y,
  (select count(*) from Vote 
   where choice NOT LIKE '%n%' AND choice LIKE '%y%') as y_not_n,
  (select count(*) from Vote 
   where (choice NOT LIKE '%y%' AND choice NOT LIKE '%n%') 
      OR (choice LIKE '%y%n%' or choice LIKE '%n%y%')) as rest
```

Working example [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b9c/19)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

[SQlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b9c/39)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN (V.choice LIKE '%n%'
AND V.choice NOT LIKE '%y%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS n_not_y,
SUM(CASE WHEN (V.choice LIKE '%y%'
AND V.choice NOT LIKE '%n%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS y_not_n
,SUM(CASE WHEN ((V.choice NOT LIKE '%y%' AND V.choice NOT LIKE '%n%') OR
     (V.choice LIKE '%y%n%' OR V.choice LIKE '%n%y%')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
AS rest

FROM Vote V
```